# CGAL Intersection returns false result

Tags: polygon, intersection, cgal

I m a bit confused about how the the `CGAL::do_intersect` works.
I thought the function returns `true` if there is a point in both polygons. As far as I m not mistaken `in` lies within `out` and I should see `true` printed out or what am I missing?

```c++
#include <CGAL/Point_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel> Polygon_2;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Polygon_2 in, out;
  in.push_back(Point_2(1,1));
  in.push_back(Point_2(1,2));
  in.push_back(Point_2(2,2));
  in.push_back(Point_2(2,1));

  out.push_back(Point_2(0,0));
  out.push_back(Point_2(3,0));
  out.push_back(Point_2(3,3));
  out.push_back(Point_2(0,3));

  std::cout << "IN intersect with OUT is " << (CGAL::do_intersect(in, out) ? "true":"false") << std::endl;
  std::cout << "OUT intersect with IN is " << (CGAL::do_intersect(out, in) ? "true":"false") << std::endl;
  std::cout.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertices in the polygon need to be counter-clockwise. The following code produces the desired output:

```
IN intersect with OUT is true
OUT intersect with IN is true
```

---

```
#include <CGAL/Point_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel> Polygon_2;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Polygon_2 in, out;
  in.push_back(Point_2(1,1));
  in.push_back(Point_2(2,1));
  in.push_back(Point_2(2,2));
  in.push_back(Point_2(1,2));

  out.push_back(Point_2(0,0));
  out.push_back(Point_2(3,0));
  out.push_back(Point_2(3,3));
  out.push_back(Point_2(0,3));

  std::cout << "IN intersect with OUT is " << (CGAL::do_intersect(in, out) ? "true":"false") << std::endl;
  std::cout << "OUT intersect with IN is " << (CGAL::do_intersect(out, in) ? "true":"false") << std::endl;
  std::cout.flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I couldn't find anything documenting this.